# how to generate result automatically calculation of two numbers?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement addition of two numbers code without using button the result should be generated automatically when we enter value into text fields from key board, help me to solve the problem.

Comment: i mean i have two text fields if i enter any values in text field1 and enter value in text field2 after entered the values addition of two text field values assigned to the text view without pressing any button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TextWatcher like below code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
```

Refer:

[TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)